# python change group to each folder in a tree

Tags: python

I have a directory structure as this:

`/app/<app_name>/server/logs`

I need to give `user_a` access read-only to logs and all the files

I created user_a with a group `group_a` and I now have to change the group to each folder leading to `logs` to allow `user_a` traverse the directory tree in order to be able to access the logs.

i then need to change  in all the folders leading to logs the group owner and give it r-x permission

some challenges I am encountering only the `logs` folder that are under a `server` folder should be changed.

I managed to change the permissions to the parent directory of the server directory but I am wondering how to go into the deeper directories until I reach `logs`

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import grp
import pwd
import os

gid = grp.getgrnam('group_a').gr_gid



for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/app'):
    for name in dirs:
        if name.startswith('server'):
           os.chown(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root,name)), -1, gid)
           os.chmod(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root,name)), stat.S_IXGRP )
```

`os.chmod` removed every other permissions instead of just adding read and execute to the group. how could I achieve this?

unfortunately pathlib is not available so i am looking for a legacy method. the server is too old to run python > 3.4.
we will upgrade next year.

there are about 100 directories to change that is why I am looking to automatize the task.

Answer (score 1):

To add a permission you need to get the current permissions first then add the new permissions.

Example:

```
import os
import stat

# get current permissions
st = os.stat(file)
# add read and execute to group
os.chmod(file, st.st_mode | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IXGRP)
```

Permissions before example:

```
-rwx------
```

Permissions after example:

```
-rwxr-x---
```

Comment: thanks but the question was how to change ownership of all the folders in the tree.